# C# - FTP transfer Access ACCDE files

Tags: c#, ms-access, ftp, vba

I wrote a simple C# program to transfer ACCDE files from a FTP server to a client's desktop. The transferring seems to work fine, however, when I open the file and try to use the program, it gives me the message "Requested type library or wizard is not a VBA project."
When I transfer the ACCDB source code, it seems to work fine. This is the transfer function:

```
private void DownloadFileFTP(string fileName, string localFilePath, bool isXmlSchema)
    {
        string ftpFilePath = redacted;
        if (isXmlSchema)
        {
            ftpFilePath = ftpFilePath + fileName;
            label3.Text = "Fetching update information...";
        }
        else
        {
            ftpFilePath = ftpFilePath + Properties.Settings.Default.Customer + "/" + fileName;
            label3.Text = "Updating " + fileName;
        }
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpFilePath);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(redacted, redacted);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        request.EnableSsl = Properties.Settings.Default.SSL;
        request.UsePassive = Properties.Settings.Default.Passive;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        Stream reader = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Create);
        while(true)
        {
            bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (bytesRead == 0)
                break;
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fs.Close();
    }
```

My questions, I suppose, are: am I doing something wrong here? Do ACCDE files not play nice with FileStreams or something? I am still quite new to .NET so any help would be very appreciated.

EDIT: It seems one of the references was causing the problem.

Comment: If you transfer the ACCDE manually does it work?

Comment: Yes, I have never had a problem transferring an ACCDE over FTP before.
Or so I had thought -- I just tried a transfer using FileZilla and had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close stream and ftpWebRequest.

Try this, made with you script, just copy/paste (fix some error if it have :) ):

```
    private void DownloadFileFTP(string fileName, string localFilePath, bool isXmlSchema)
{
    FileStream fs = null;

    try
    {
        fileName = Regex.Replace(fileName.ToString(), @"\s.*$", "").Trim();

        string ftpFilePath = redacted;

        if (isXmlSchema)
        {
            ftpFilePath = ftpFilePath + fileName;
            label3.Text = "Fetching update information...";
        }
        else
        {
            ftpFilePath = ftpFilePath + Properties.Settings.Default.Customer + "/" + fileName;
            label3.Text = "Updating " + fileName;
        }

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpFilePath);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(redacted, redacted);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        request.EnableSsl = Properties.Settings.Default.SSL;
        request.UsePassive = Properties.Settings.Default.Passive;

        int bytesRead = 0;
        int bufferSize = 2048;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        Stream reader = request.GetResponseStream();

        bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        fs = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Create);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        reader.Close();
        request.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        label3.Text = "Error: " + ex.ToString;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fs != null)
        {
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```